# Gt 710 cycle render not working

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I bought an graphics card nvidia gt 710.After installing the driver when i open blender cycle render blender stop suddenly.Its happening every time when i click cycle render.

Comment: Don't expect much from that card. It is a very low end of the GPUs.

Comment: Why cycle render not working in that gpu